# Mutt in bash script raises an error in python (flask) application

Tags: python, bash, flask, mutt

I believe that the main problem here is with mutt command:
`mutt -s "Title" -a $file -- "$address" < $DIR/message.txt`.
If I delete it from the script, there is no error so maybe someone will find out what is going on.

This is a python application using flask. Here is the problematic method:

```
@app.route('/send', methods=['POST'])
def send():
start_date = '2016-10-20'
end_date = '2016-10-28'
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
script = path + '/script.sh'
address = 'my@mail.com'
subprocess.check_call([script, start_date, end_date, address])
return json.dumps({
    'message': 'Your message is sent!'
})
```

Subprocess runs script :

```
#!/bin/bash
start_date="$1"
end_date="$2"
address="$3"
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
$file="My_super_file"
out=$(R -e "rmarkdown::render('$DIR/generate_file.Rmd', output_file = $file)")
mutt -s "Title" -a $file -- "$address" < $DIR/message.txt
```

When the file is generated, I get such error:

```
[2016-10-28 16:03:06,857] ERROR in app: Exception on /send [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "Users/admin/mydemoapp/app/appdemo/views.py", line 18, in send
    subprocess.check_call([script, start_date, end_date, address])
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '['/Users/admin/mydemoapp/app/appdemo/script.sh', '2016-10-20', '2016-10-28', u'my@mail.com']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: What is the intended purpose of the line `- generating $file -`?  That's not valid bash syntax.  Are you intending to `echo "generating $file"`?  Also, from the Python exception info, it appears to be attempting to call the script with a Unicode representation of `my@mail.com`.  That doesn't seem like what you want.

Comment: With `- generating $file -` I wanted to hide part of the code that generates script, which is not important here.
Nom I do not want to run the script with unicode representation

Comment: The `$file` variable is also not set in the example you provided.  It doesn't have a space in the name, does it?  If so, you would need to quote it in the `mutt` line.  And probably also the `$DIR` reference at the end.  `mutt -s "Title" -a "$file" -- "$address" < "$DIR/message.txt"`

Comment: @eddiem The problem was that the script tried to call email address with unicode representation. I converted it to string and it started working! Thank you!